# How to limit Google WebService Places Autocomplete Query to Basic SKU only

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

Currently when I use my query code

```
  url:https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/jsoninput=h&language=en&location=60.451401,22.266935999999987&radius=30000&types=geocode&components=country:fin&key=API_KEY
```

It will also get Atmosphere Data and Contact DATA, is it possible to limit the query to return Basic data only, which is free.

Comment: Can you please add your actual code? (How you're parsing the response, data types, etc.)

Comment: There is really no need. Above is what you can call via browser for example. But with above query It will not LIMIT it to basic data but instead it will gather all data (Ex. Atmospehere) and it will cost more

Comment: Place autocomplete doesn't generate SKUs for basic, atmosphere or contact data. These SKUs are generated later when you request a place details. Have a look at documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session

Comment: I don't quite understand. Now if I do the webquery (like in OP) I do get additional costs? "Places Details request generates Data SKUs (Basic, Contact, and/or Atmosphere) – depending on the fields that are specified in the request. If you do not specify fields in the Place Details request, all Data SKUs are triggered (Basic, Contact, and Atmosphere). To avoid paying for data that you don't need, call Autocomplete.setFields() to specify only the place data that you will use."